# paperclip No handler found for "file.jpg" rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, image-uploading

I'm having problem with setting up paperclip gem in one of me apps.
I get `No handler found for` error message when i try to save uploaded file.

Things that I've done

- migration:

  ```
  add_attachment :orders, :file
  ```
- model:

  ```
  has_attached_file :file  
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  ```
- controller:

  ```
  def order_params  
    params.require(:order).permit(:file)
  ```
- view:

  ```
  form_tag url, method: :post, html: {multipart: true}  
  ...  
  = file_field_tag 'order[file]', disabled: true, id: 'mtd_file',accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg'
  ```

When I try to execute in my controller `Order.create params[order]` I get error

> No handler found for "file.jpg"

When I look into `order[file]` param I see that it's a string `file.jpg` (name of uploaded file).

Comment: I think you have not generated migration properly... `rails generate paperclip order file`  did you try this???

Comment: Try `form_tag url, method: :post, multipart: true` as specified by http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: @Sontya could you answer the question6 and i'll mark it as correct& worked like charm!

Comment: glad it helped you. added as answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the below line of code, you don't have to pass `mulitpart` as `html` hash

```
form_tag url, method: :post, multipart: true
```

For `form_for` you have to pass `multipart` in `html` hash

```
form_for(@user), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
```

For more info, you can refer to the documentation: [RailsGuides - Form Helpers - 5 Uploading Files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)